# SQL Query Correctness

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to find `carid` which has taken most trips with distinct customers. I don't want a complete solution as I have an idea about how to do it. But when I run the query I get the error:

```
Table 'test.v' doesn't exist
1 statement failed.
```

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (
        SELECT carid, COUNT(DISTINCT cusid) AS counter
        FROM trips
        GROUP BY carid
    ) v
)
WHERE v.counter = (
        SELECT MAX(counter)
        FROM v
)
```

When I select `v.counter=2` I get the proper result. Can anyone explain me what is happening?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: If your question was about MS SQL Server, you could use [`with`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) or [`over`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to accomplish that. With MySQL, [answer by @GurV](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42591833/5221149) is likely the best option.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can't directly use alias like that. You will need to rewrite the subquery again.

Try this:

```
select *
from (
    select carid, count(distinct cusid) as counter
    from trips
    group by carid
    ) v
where v.counter = (
        select max(counter)
        from (
            select count(distinct cusid) as counter
            from trips
            group by carid
            ) t
        )
```

It's not clear which DBMS you are using. If you are using SQL Server, you could use CTE:

```
with v
as (
    select carid, count(distinct cusid) as counter
    from trips
    group by carid
    )
select *
from v
where counter = (
        select max(counter)
        from v
        )
```

Comment: why is that? isn't v has been created as an temporary table when from statement was executing and after that where clause can reference v table?

Comment: @Varun - Yes temporary table is created but it's not available for querying like that. It's already being queried. One option is using CTE (Common table expressions) if you are using SQL server (added an example in the answer).